# How to Run my old Unreal Engine 4 project?

Tags: unreal-engine4

Years ago I build my project and then I lost it, now after lots of struggle I have recovered it from my old HDD drive, but now when I try to run it to build project files, I have the following error.

[image: ERROR SCREEN]

Comment: That's not valid C#, you've got an "if" block directly inside the class declaration rather than inside a method. Perhaps your file was corrupted.

Comment: but the project is using C++ ... from where C# jumps in?

Comment: Unreal's build system is C# (those files have .cs extensions). Build rules for C++ modules are written in C# files, e.g. MyModule.build.cs.